# New-ApplicationAccessPolicy in Exchange 365 for AppRegistration is not working to restrict access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to implement a restriction by using the `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy` cmdlet to prevent sending emails from any user account when using a given App Registration. But the emails (and other actions such as reading messages) are still working. For example, I don't want the application to be able to send or read email for the user `mateoj@iadbsec.onmicrosoft.com`.

If I review the permissions in an Exchange PowerShell console, it shows that the access for this user-application combination is denied:

```
Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity mateoj@iadbsec.onmicrosoft.com -AppId f5990b66-5e57-4d29-b990-79580009fb7a

RunspaceId        : 6800e63c-6ed3-40ca-a7b0-8aa114a3488a
AppId             : f5990b66-5e57-4d29-b990-79580009fb7a
Mailbox           : mateoj
MailboxId         : 0b5221ff-c190-47c5-8c1c-50435b5abfee
MailboxSid        : S-1-5-21-3773200467-1648347138-3333334462-20495337
AccessCheckResult : Denied
```

But I am still able to read or send emails for that account.

The user already consented to permissions for a previous version of this application in AD, but the Exchange Policy should deny the requests.

[image: Permissions in AD -> User -> Applicactions -> Permissions]

This is my source code:

```
string graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/0b5221ff-c190-47c5-8c1c-50435b5abfee/messages"; 
        
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
        private async void CallGraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
            var app = App.PublicClientApp;
            ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
            TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;

            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

            try
            {
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

                try
                {
                    authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle) // optional, used to center the browser on the window
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (MsalException msalex)
                {
                    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
                return;
            }

            if (authResult != null)
            {
                ResultText.Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
                DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
                this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
                
        public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return content;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

The Token that the application is getting contains not only the requested scopes "user.read" but all the scopes that the user already consented:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "nonce": "0ehQiH41_yQ12B5YRoxiXQPSTNvNbcL8tgL5Rn2axhY",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU",
  "kid": "YMELHT0gvb0mxoSDoYfomjqfjYU"
}.{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/35463e7c-329a-4bda-8176-329ba27c9300/",
  "iat": 1587492891,
  "nbf": 1587492891,
  "exp": 1587496791,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "42dgYJgXuZKBP7Q/mOHxzc1NZ1VObFt+Jzhlg1hPSl1iBn+wRAEA",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "ASP.NET Graph Tutorial",
  "appid": "f5990b66-5e57-4d29-b990-79580009fb7a",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "family_name": "J",
  "given_name": "Mateo",
  "ipaddr": "100.15.106.170",
  "name": "Mateo J",
  "oid": "0b5221ff-c190-47c5-8c1c-50435b5abfee",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "10032000AF94C708",
  "scp": "Calendars.Read email Mail.Read Mail.Send openid profile User.Read",
  "sub": "7RUo9SosiVWj38mVDqx_TLjx9cke-9kXqlq-UzPydHk",
  "tid": "35463e7c-329a-4bda-8176-329ba27c9300",
  "unique_name": "mateoj@iadbsec.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "mateoj@iadbsec.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "BarWkwo_skyYDqHDUKYnAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_st": {
    "sub": "m0q26l-BwZKjl1W3FHV0jn1iRfCEAiIdE4BNu3gQ_F8"
  },
  "xms_tcdt": 1586707572
}.[Signature]
```

These are the permissions that the AppRegistration has:
[image]

Why is  the application still able to send and read emails even if the application access policy indicates that for this user-application the permissions are denied?

Answer (score 0):

ApplicationAccessPolicies only support Application permissions and client credentials via the OAuth flow. Delegate permissions are not supported.

If you would like to make sure that your delegate permission app is not used by certain users, we suggest following the steps listed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/disable-user-sign-in-portal:

> ### Prerequisites
>
> To disable how a user signs in, you need:
>
> - An Azure account with an active subscription. Create an account for free.
> - One of the following roles: Global Administrator, Cloud Application Administrator, Application Administrator, or owner of the service principal.
>
> ### Disable how a user signs in
>
> 1. Sign in to the Azure portal as the global administrator for your directory.
> 2. Search for and select Azure Active Directory.
> 3. Select Enterprise applications.
> 4. Search for the application you want to disable a user from signing in, and select the application.
> 5. Select Properties.
> 6. Select No for Enabled for users to sign-in?.
> 7. Select Save.
>
> ### Use Azure AD PowerShell to disable an unlisted app
>
> Ensure you have installed the AzureAD module (use the command `Install-Module -Name AzureAD`). In case you are prompted to install a NuGet module or the new Azure Active Directory V2 PowerShell module, type Y and press ENTER.
>
> If you know the AppId of an app that doesn't appear on the Enterprise apps list (for example, because you deleted the app or the service principal hasn't yet been created due to the app being pre-authorized by Microsoft), you can manually create the service principal for the app and then disable it by using [an] AzureAD PowerShell cmdlet:
>
> ```powershell
> # The AppId of the app to be disabled
> $appId = "{AppId}"
>
> # Check if a service principal already exists for the app
> $servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
> if ($servicePrincipal) {
>     # Service principal exists already, disable it
>     Set-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -AccountEnabled $false  
> } else {
>     # Service principal does not yet exist, create it and disable it at the same time
>     $servicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId $appId -AccountEnabled $false  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the app(service principal) from "Enterprise Applications" list on azure portal directly because the user consent operation is actually create an enterprise application(service principal). So after we delete it from "Enterprise Applications" list, the next time when we request for user consent(with only `user.read` scope), it will re-create an enterprise application with only "user.read" permission. The access token will not contain the permissions such as `mail.read`...